# What is contained in a datacontrols.dcx file ? Is it contained in the .war file of the application?

Tags: oracle-adf

I know that `databindings.cpx` has a `dataControlUsages` node that that contains information about all the `datacontrols` used by the application .I also learnt that `databindings.cpx` acts a a binding context at run time and page def elements contained within it acts as a binding container for each page at run time . But there is also a datacontrols.cpx file present . My questions are :

1. Is it an application level file ? What is its purpose ?
2. Or is it `ADF specific` and doesn't really depend on the application ? In other words will there be a `datacontrols.cpx` file in my web application `.war` file if I use pre buillt datacontrols by ADF framework  ?
3. Will that situation change if I write a new `datacontrol` for my application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datacontrols.dcx exists when you create custom data controls based on POJOs, web services, EJBs and the like.  It describes or stores the metadata about the data control, essentially the wiring required to make the underlying service (e.g. POJOs, web services) exposed through the data control palette, and the runtime settings so the ViewController layer knows how to make use of it.

In addition as JDeveloper evolves there is more functionality being built into the datacontrols.dcx.  You probably know from ADF BC you can build in validation rules and control hints for attributes.  These sort of mechanisms are now being built into custom data controls too, such that it doesn't matter what sort of data control you consume in your application, it will give a consistent and sophisticated set of features to the consumer (that being the ViewController layer).

As of the current release of JDeveloper (11g) the documentation on data controls is somewhat lacking, but (no promises) this should be rectified upon the 12c release.

Comment: I believe you were talking about datacontrols.dcx and not databindings.cpx? I edited your answer. Feel free to correct if you think it is not right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Answers to your questions 
1)DataControls.dcx is not an application level file
  Purpose:
  DataControls.dcx file is used to store the Data Controls for  Java Bean(POJO), Web Service,
  EJB, URL Service  (i.e., non-ADF BC Components ) 

2) Yes DataControls.dcx is ADF specific , You don't find it in the plain Java Enterprise application

There are no pre-built Data Controls in ADF. Data Controls are part of ADF Application
Yes ADF application war contains the DataControls.dcx file 

3) As mention in the above ADF framework does not have pre-built controls. 
   If you create your own Data control  in your application , it will be available
```